# How to set a value of an object inside a state to a HTML input value in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a React app with the following component. Inside this component, I have a state of objects and inside those objects, there are some values stored to be set as some HTML input values. **The problem is, when I set these values as a state value to the HTML input, it won't apply. The HTML input is empty.** I can set those values as a value reference by assigning them to variables, but then I can't change the value using `onChange` function. How can I solve this?

```
state.questionsData = [{
   order: 1,
   question: "Question 1",
   questionType: "scq",
   scq: [
      { optionId: 1, optionName: "op1" },
      { optionId: 2, optionName: "op2" },
   ]}
]
```

**The following is not working. HTML input value will be empty**

```
addOptionToState = (id, optionId) => {
   var newOption = <input
                    type="text"
                    value={
                          this.state.questionsData.forEach(element => {
                              if (element.order === id) {
                                 element.scq.forEach(each => {
                                    if (each.optionId === optionId) {
                                          // this console shows the value, but return doesn't work
                                          console.log(each.optionName)
                                          return each.optionName
                                    }
                                 })
                              }
                          })
                    }
                    onChange={e => this.handleQuestionOptions(e, id)}
                   />
}
```

**The following is working. But I'm unable to edit value since the value is not a state value anymore**

```
addOptionToState = (id, optionId) => {

   var stateValue = "";

   this.state.questionsData.forEach(element => {
      if (element.order === id) {
         element.scq.forEach(each => {
            if (each.optionId === optionId) {
               stateValue = each.optionName
            }
         })
      }
   })

   var newOption = <input
                    type="text"
                    value={ stateValue }
                    onChange={e => this.handleQuestionOptions(e, id)}
                   />
}
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Is there only a single input or multiple inputs ? Also, is the `id` parameter in `addOptionToState` unique ?

Comment: @usafder yes id is unique, and there are multiple input elements adding dynamically

Comment: Then maybe having an object `inputValues` inside the `state` would work.

Instead of using `stateValue = each.optionName` try using `this.setState({ inputValues: { ...this.state.inputValues, [id]: each.optionName } })`

and then in the `value` prop just assign `this.state.inputValues[id]`.

Comment: @usafder you mean to set the input value to a new state and assign that new state to the `value` prop right? But in the onChange function, I'm updating the original state; therefore I can't see even I change the value in the input element

Comment: It would help if you edited your original post and showed what your onChangeFunction is doing. I see you have your questions data defined in state right now, so you would need to define another state variable to go along with that. along the lines of what @usafder was saying.